# buy - sell conditions with EMA 200

Tags: pine-script

what I write in the strategy for the following condition: 1) do not enter short if the price is above the 200 EMA
2) do not enter long if the price is below the 200 EMA
----- at which point of the strategy should these conditions be written?

Answer (score 2):

```
strategy("200ema", overlay=true)  

ema1=ema(close,1)
ema2=ema(close,200)

buy= crossover(ema1,ema2)
sell=crossunder(ema1,ema2)

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    
if (sell)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
```

This is a simple script that will show buy/sell when ema1 cross ema2.

And if you want to do do something like "Price must be above 200 in order to trigger buy and below 200 to trigger sell"

just add this

```
strategy("200ema", overlay=true)  

ema1=ema(close,1)
ema2=ema(close,200)

bf=ema1>ema2
sf=ema1<ema2
buy= (your strategy) and bf
sell=(your strategy) and sf

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

if (sell)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
```